# How to add new space to build on in Dragons of Atlantis?

Tags: dragons-of-atlantis

I thought I'd try out Dragons of Atlantis on Google Plus, one of the quests requires me to build three of each resource buildings, but I'm short on one patch of land:

[image]

So I'm wondering: **how do I add a patch of land to build on?** Or do I automatically get this once I reach a higher level?

Comment: +1 easy access to the game, I'll see if I see something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just read the description of upgrading my Fortress to Level 4 and it says: Occupy 3 Wildernesses, accept 3 Reinforcement Marches and **open 3 more Resource Sites.**

[image]

So upgrading my Fortress did the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is an item called Outpost Warp which mentions that higher level plains allow for more wildernesses to be controlled. The customer help says the following:

> You must control a Plain of an equal or higher level in addition to the one your Outpost already occupies. If you transport your Outpost to a higher level Plain you will be given the ability to own more Wildernesses.
>
> — [KABAM Customer Help - Dragons of Atlantis: Outpost Warp](http://kabam.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/276)

So, I went looking further using some terms, and encountered [this guide to building a second city](http://www.squidoo.com/buildasecondcity):

1. **Be a Level 7 (Baronet)**: Do other quests first.
2. **Have 10 Friends who play Kingdoms of Camelot:** Google+ games are all about social.
3. **Get a Second City Deed:** Get 10 friends, finish the quest or buy the item with money.
4. **Conquer a Plain:** Choose a wise location (far away, so it survives), level doesn't matter.

The page also notes other useful information so you should read it, such as:

> Not only will a second city allow you to conquer additional wildernesses, it allows you to raise buildings and armies simultaneously with your first city. Building a second city is a critical component to gameplay. By having one built, it allows you to double your resource production, double your army, and double your might!

Comment: Well I don't have an army to begin with, so conquering wasn't an option. Guess I had to be patient and unlock higher level buildings.

Comment: @IvoFipse: Oh well, we've covered both cases now. :)